# Switching users freezes desktop

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, xorg, intel-graphics, freeze

Since I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10, I've been having problems switching between users. When I run `Logout > Switch User` in X, the screen often stops updating and the keyboard stops responding to input (the LEDs don't update). Occasionally, switching users will work, but switching back often causes the same freeze. Switching to a text console also occasionally freezes the machine.

I've got onboard 865g Intel graphics card. `lspci -k` tells me:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: IBM Device 0285
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

I don't know if it's related, but X doesn't always seem to update when the screen changes. When I hide [Guake](http://guake.org/), the screen doesn't always update. I didn't have this problem before I upgraded.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: It might be better if you report a bug on launchpad.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you've managed to solve the issue or the issue solved itself via an update. If not then this problem certainly does need to be reported to [the xorg bug tracker](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bugs). Make sure to include the `xorg.log` `dmesg` log files (available in /var/log ) and the output from `lspci -nn`

You can also simply run the command to report the problem and collect all the information required:

`ubuntu-bug xorg`

You can find some lovely information about how to track the issue and what information will be very helpful here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve the problem. I'll give your suggestion a shot and see if I get any upstream love. Thanks.